# Getting node error while running npn install

Tags: node.js, angular

I am getting below error while I am trying to run node install on my tekton pipeline.My node version is 16.

```
npm ERR! 
code EPIPE npm ERR! 
syscall write npm ERR!
errno -32 npm ERR! 
write EPIPE
```

I confirmed, I do not have any network connectivity issue. My Nexus repository is accessible(no firewall rules). I am not able to figure our why this issue is. I see a 400 on

```
npm http fetch POST 400 https://www.nexus.mycon.com/repository/npmjs-group/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 476ms
npm http fetch POST 400 https://www.nexus.mycon.com/repository/npmjs-group/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 81ms
npm verb audit error HttpErrorGeneral: 400 Bad Request - POST https://www.nexus.mycon.com/repository/npmjs-group/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick
npm verb audit error     at /usr/node-v16.19.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:95:15
npm verb audit error     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
npm verb audit error     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
npm verb audit error     at async Map.[getReport] (/usr/node-v16.19.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/audit-report.js:335:21)
npm verb audit error     at async Map.run (/usr/node-v16.19.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/audit-report.js:106:19)
npm verb audit error  HttpErrorGeneral: 400 Bad Request - POST https://www.nexus.mycon.com/repository/npmjs-group/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick
npm verb audit error     at /usr/node-v16.19.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:95:15
npm verb audit error     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
npm verb audit error     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
npm verb audit error     at async Map.[getReport] (/usr/node-v16.19.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/audit-report.js:335:21)
npm verb audit error     at async Map.run (/usr/node-v16.19.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/audit-report.js:106:19) {
npm verb audit error   headers: [Object: null prototype] {
npm verb audit error     date: [ 'Wed, 13 Sep 2023 14:26:55 GMT' ],
npm verb audit error     'strict-transport-security': [ 'max-age=7776000' ],
npm verb audit error     'set-cookie': [
npm verb audit error       'dtCookie=v_4_srv_35_sn_CF01212BBD7112C8B91D344E2BE065CC_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3A14d8122d44bc9f23_1; Path=/; Domain=.mycon.com'
npm verb audit error     ],
npm verb audit error     'server-timing': [ 'dtRpid;desc="-1194900750", dtSInfo;desc="0"' ],
npm verb audit error     'x-oneagent-js-injection': [ 'true' ],
npm verb audit error     server: [ 'Nexus/3.38.1-01 (PRO)' ],
npm verb audit error     'x-content-type-options': [ 'nosniff' ],
npm verb audit error     'content-security-policy': [
npm verb audit error       'sandbox allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-top-navigation'
npm verb audit error     ],
npm verb audit error     'x-xss-protection': [ '1; mode=block' ],
npm verb audit error     'content-type': [ 'application/json' ],
npm verb audit error     'content-length': [ '228' ],
npm verb audit error     'x-fetch-attempts': [ '1' ]
npm verb audit error   },
npm verb audit error   statusCode: 400,
npm verb audit error   code: 'E400',
npm verb audit error   method: 'POST',
npm verb audit error   uri: 'https://www.nexus.mycon.com/repository/npmjs-group/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick',
npm verb audit error   body: <Buffer 0a 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d 3d ... 178 more bytes>,
npm verb audit error   pkgid: 'quick'
npm verb audit error }
npm timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 879ms
npm timing reify:audit Completed in 880ms
npm verb stack Error: write EPIPE
npm verb stack     at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16)
npm verb cwd /workspace/source
npm verb Linux 4.18.0-372.64.1.el8_6.x86_64
npm verb node v16.19.1
npm verb npm  v8.19.3
npm ERR! code EPIPE
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno -32
npm ERR! write EPIPE
npm verb exit -32
```

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74095146/gitlab-ci-npm-err-code-epipe-on-every-build-while-running-npm-install

Comment: From Node16 on we see the audit it turned on, so for now we disabled audit by adding --no-audit npm run --no-audit...

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar error before, and the solution that worked for someone else was to completely **uninstall** both npm and Node.js from their system, including removing any **environment variables** associated with them.

Afterward, they reinstalled ***npm and Node.js*** to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because in node16 images the audit was enabled. We turned off the audit using --no-audit to fix the issue for now.